# Service Worker failure - Redirected response while RedirectMode is not "follow"

Tags: javascript, redirect, service-worker, offline-caching

Browser: Firefox 58.0.2 (64-bit)

I'm trying to write a [very simple service worker](http://is.am/yafp) to cache content for offline mode, following the guidance [here](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/codelabs/offline/#get_the_sample_code) and [here](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/offline-cookbook/).

When I load the page the first time, the service worker is installed properly.  I can confirm it's running by looking in about:debugging#workers.

However, at this point if I attempt to refresh the page (whether online or offline), or navigate to any other page in the site, I get the following error:

> The site at https://[my url] has experienced a network protocol
>   violation that cannot be repaired.
>
> The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because an error in
>   the data transmission was detected.
>
> Please contact the website owners to inform them of this problem.

The console shows this error:

> Failed to load ‘https://[my url]’. A ServiceWorker passed a redirected Response to FetchEvent.respondWith() while RedirectMode is not ‘follow’.

In Chrome, I get this:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'ServiceWorkerGlobalScope': Cannot construct a Request with a Request whose mode is 'navigate' and a non-empty RequestInit.

Per [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40274429/1502289), I added the { redirect: "follow" } parameter to the fetch() function, but to no avail.

(Yes I did manually uninstall the Service Worker from the about:debugging page after making the change.)

From what I understand, however, it's the response, not the fetch, that's causing the problem, right?  And this is due to my server issuing a redirect when serving the requested content?

So how do I deal with redirects in the service worker?  There are obviously going to be some, and I still want to cache the data.

Answer (score 1):

Partly spun off from https://superuser.com/a/1388762/84988

I sometimes get the problem with Gmail with Waterfox 56.2.6 on FreeBSD-CURRENT. (Waterfox 56 was based on Firefox 56.0.2.) Sometimes when simply reloading the page; sometimes when loading the page in a restored session; and so on.

[FetchEvent.respondWith() | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FetchEvent/respondWith) begins with an alert:

> **This is an experimental technology** …

At a glance, the two bugs found by https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/buglist.cgi?quicksearch=FetchEvent.respondWith%28%29 are unrelated.

Across the Internet there are numerous reports, from users of Gmail with Firefox, of *Corrupted Content Error*, *network protocol violation* etc.. Found:

- Mozilla bug [1495275 - Corrupted Content Error for gmail](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1495275)